# How can i mocking unittest sqlite connection in python

Tags: python, sqlite, unit-testing, mocking

I am using Python 3.6, under the Pycharm environment.

I would like to mock `sqlite3.connect`. For example in `TestDatabase` (see below), I would like `test_sqlite3_connect` to return the string connection rather than an actual `self.db_conn` object.

I have tried it, but that does not work.

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, conn_string):
        self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect(conn_string, check_same_thread=False)
        self.db_conn.row_factory = self.dict_factory
```

```
class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.db_conn = db.Database('videodetector.db')


    def test_sqlite3_connect_success(self):
        sqlite3.connect = MagicMock(return_value='connection succeeded')
        db_conn=db.Database('videodetector.db')
        sqlite3.connect.assert_called_with('videodetector.db')
        self.assertEqual(db_conn, 'connection succeeded')
```

Comment: What do you expect `'connection succeeded'.row_factory = self.dict_factory` to do?

Comment: def dict_factory(self, cursor, row):
        row_dict = {}
        for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
            row_dict[col[0]] = row[idx] if row[idx] is not None else ""
        return row_dict
Test passed when I commented there but I need 'self.db_conn.row_factory = self.dict_factory' to test this function.